# Overriden method: which method will be called if the message is sent to an object of superclass?

Tags: objective-c

I have the subclass `Foo` of the class `Bar`:

```
@interface Foo : Bar
{ 
- (void)methodName;
}
```

It has the `methodName` method which overrides the `Bar` class' method.

I have the object of the `Foo`'s superclass:

```
Bar *bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
```

Then I send the message to this object:

```
[bar methodName];
```

Why is the `Foo`'s implementation of the `methodName` is executed instead of the `Bar`'s? This method's implementation in `Foo` completely overrides the one in `Bar`, it doesn't call `[super methodName]`. Pretty obvious to me that if the object were of the subclass, the subclass' implementation would be called, but why is it executed when the message is sent to the object of superclass?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not happen. Your mistake is elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be. You might want to try calling `[bar class]` before `[bar methodName]` to make sure that you really have an instance of Bar. If it really is an instance of Bar, I can't think of any way that it might be calling the method of the Foo subclass.

Comment: Thank you. I will check carefully if bar is really an instance of Bar.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing some little detail in your code. The overridden method is going to be invoked only on the object of the class that overrides it. Don't you call `[super method]` in Foo? Here is an example code:

```
@interface Bar : NSObject
-(void)method;
@end

@implementation Bar
-(void)method {
    NSLog(@"Bar");
}
@end

@interface Foo : Bar
@end

@implementation Foo
// override method
-(void)method {
    NSLog(@"Foo");
}
@end
```

Invoke them so:

```
[[[Bar alloc] init] method]; // writes Bar
[[[Foo alloc] init] method]; // writes Foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Shame on me, I have found out that my object is really an instance of subclass. Anyways, as I'm new to Objective-C, it was useful for me to hear how things should work in this case.

Comment: Sure, this happens to anyone. If you can upvote, I would appreciate.

Comment: Done, thank you once again :)